# CSV have junk using jQuery DataTables (UTF 8)

Tags: jquery, datatables, export-to-csv

Have junk in export using client side feature of jQuery DataTables.

My export to csv result is following :

```
ï»¿"No" Genre Name  Status
31  Satire  Enable
```

my function for getting csv ready is following:

```
dTable = $('#territoryTable').dataTable({
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ Records",
                    "sZeroRecords": "<center>No Record Found!</center>",
                    //"sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ Records",
                    //"sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 Records",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total Records)",
                },
                drawCallback: function () {
                    $("#territoryTable").find("td").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).hasClass('dataTables_empty')) {
                            $('#deviceTable_paginate').hide();
                        } else
                        {
                            $('#deviceTable_paginate').show();
                        }
                    });
                },
                "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {

                    var numStart = this.fnPagingInfo().iStart;

                    var index = numStart + iDisplayIndexFull + 1;
                    $("td:first", nRow).html(index);
                    return nRow;
                },
                "paging": true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": false,
                "autoWidth": false,
                responsive: true,
                bJQueryUI: false,
                bProcessing: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                bFilter: true,
                //multipleSelection: true,
                iDisplayLength: 10,
                sAjaxSource: "{{ path('disney_admin_os_management_list_json') }}",
                aoColumns: [
                    {"sName": "Id"},
                    {"sName": "os_name"},
                    {"sName": "os_description"},
                    {"sName": "os_version"},
                    {"sName": "status"},
                    {"sName": "Id", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, "className": "text-center tableIcon"}
                ],
```

note:
when i use this direct link of js file all works well:
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js
but when i use this js file after downloading to my local project it makes problem of junk.

Comment: Please check out how to create a [mcve] for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

We were having this issue and found that our minifier, which packaged the datatables JS files into single file, was responsible for this broken character.

When we excluded buttons.html5.min.js from the minifier and loaded it directly it worked fine.

The use of a minifier may or may not be your problem, but I suspect you have disturbed the character encoding. In our case, the minifier was disturbing the encoding.

This broken character is probably the Byte Order Mark and you may need to be careful about preserving the character encoding in the process of downloading the file from datatables.net and transferring it to your project. I.e. If you FTP the file, make sure you are using Binary transfer mode.